# Why Ejb Interface throwing NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ejb-3.0

I am calling my Ejb bean from My Test class.In test class i am using static  keyword in front of here userService because i am accessing the userService from the static context(from main method.)

**Note:** Also If i donot uses the static keyword in front of userService then also i got same error.

```
public class Test {

    @Inject 
    private static UserService userService;

    public Test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        userService.doSomething("hello");
    }

}
```

I setup an EJB 3 interface/implementation looking like this...

**UserService (interface)**

```
package business;

public interface UserService {

    public String doSomething();

}
```

**UserServiceBean (implementation)**

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class UserServiceBean implements UserService{

    public UserServiceBean() {
    }

    @Override
    public String doSomething() {
        return "Work done!";
    }

}
```

When i am calling **doSomething method** of UserServiceBean  class using interface from my Test class. Its giving me error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Please explain me why this error is coming.

Comment: `userService` is null, and nothing is assigning it a value. From the `@Inject` annotation I assume you *expected* something to do so, but it's not clear to me that you've actually configured such behavior. I would not expect, for instance, a `static` field to be injectable.

Comment: I used static here because i am accessing the userService from the static context. Or purpose of injecting the UserService is just to get the output from EJB bean(UserServiceBean ) by calling it. My question is very clear.

Comment: What container you are using?

Comment: Its not duplicate open your eyes. It is another case with different solution. It is only comes around nullpointer. @rkosegi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting Null pointer exception because userService in class Test is static. Injection does not works for static fields. Remove static keyword from field userService. define it like

```
 @Inject 
 private  UserService userService;
```

Reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/do_s_and_don_ts

Refer this link for how to invoke the service method:
http://www.coderpanda.com/ejb-stateless-session-bean-example/

Comment: After removing the static key word it also giving nullPointer error.

Comment: can you give me a example for more explanation.

Comment: Please share your entire piece of code. You can update your question to add the entire code. If you have any configuration file, then do share that also.

Comment: Can you refer the this link http://www.coderpanda.com/ejb-stateless-session-bean-example/   There might be some code issue when you are invoking the method

Comment: Thanks for your link @reena . But even i didnot find the answer. I also used your getter setter method it also not working. For project configuration i simply made a dynamic project then make only these 3 classes which i have wrote to just only test my output for learning purpose.

Comment: @bharti "*removing the static key word it also giving nullPointer error*" well yes, you can't just blindly delete things and expect your code to suddenly work. *Something* must assign `userService` a non-null value, otherwise you'll get an NPE. What, exactly, do you expect to assign it a value, and where in your code is that happening?